# AppIntent when using SwiftData does not synchronized MainApp and Widget

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

main app not updating after AppIntent perform

I executed perform in the widget, and I confirmed that the data has definitely changed. However, the data is not being updated in the main app.

"I could internally identify some changes. What I did was sorting the values using sortBy, so there were indeed changes. However, the data is not getting updated. I've provided a repository that reproduces the same issue I'm facing."

thanks!

**Same Issue:**
`https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/18nzj59/swiftdata_main_app_not_updating_after_appintent`

Anyone encounter the main app not updating after doing an app intent perform? I've seen so many threads about this issue but no solutions.

Is this an apple bug? Are all the devs doing something wrong?

**Github repo to reproduce:** https://github.com/iandundas/WidgetIntentNotUpdatingApp

**Relevant discussions on Apple Developer forums:**

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/739741

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/737245

Is this an apple bug? Are all the devs doing something wrong?